# How to get txt file into CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file that has "5 values". I have the following information

```
[LENGTH, START INDEX(1 instead of 0), TYPE]
[4, 1, "TypeA"]
[11, 5, "TypeB"]
[5, 16, "Charles"]
```

Assuming these instructions have to be processed for each line of text, what is the most efficient way to do this in python on a line by line to generate a CSV from the input file (note that the spaces and characters do not matter for any variation of the line. The same instructions apply)?

i.e. If this was a line in the file:

```
ABCD EFGHIJK LMNOP QR
```

The "csv version" result for that processed line based on the instructions above would be:

```
"ABCD ", "EFGHIJK LMN", "OP QR"
```

Without the trailing spaces would be:

> "ABCD", "EFGHIJK LMN", "OP QR"

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "instructions"?

Comment: I don't see how your specs match your output.  You say start is 1-indexed, but you need to start at a 0-indexed 5 to get `EFG..`, and you need to start at a 0-indexed 16 to get `OP QR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't see how your specs match your desired output-- they don't seem to be consistent.  So for the purposes of this answer, I'm going to change your `TypeA` "instruction", to make it consistent with the others.

You can use string slicing and the `csv` module to turn your fixed-width format file into a `csv`, though.  For example, something like

```
import csv

specs = [[5, 0, "TypeA"],
         [11, 5, "TypeB"],
         [5, 16, "Charles"]]

with open("filename.txt") as infile, open("out.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    names = [s[-1] for s in specs]
    writer.writerow(names)
    for line in infile:
        row = [line[start:start+length] for length, start, name in specs]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

would produce

```
dsm@notebook:~/coding$ cat out.csv 
"TypeA","TypeB","Charles"
"ABCD ","EFGHIJK LMN","OP QR"
```

---

If you're going to be doing a lot of processing of tabular data, then I'd recommend looking at the [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) library, which makes this much simpler:

```
import pandas as pd, csv
df = pd.read_fwf("filename.txt", widths=(5,11,5), names=["TypeA", "TypeB", "Charles"])
df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Comment: Is re an equivalent function like "read_fwf" but reads from input structure like array of text?

Comment: I don't know what an array of text is.  Do you mean a string, or a list of strings?

Comment: Yes, like a list of strings. So that I can have a version of the "txt" file in code in a strucutre (like a list of strings or some python structure that represents it) without having to pass the name of the text file. So itd be like pd.read_fwf(myStringListOrStructure,...)

Comment: You can use the `StringIO` module, which lets you make an object which takes a string and then pretends it's a file.  `from StringIO import StringIO` and then `pd.read_fwf(StringIO(''.join(some_list_of_strings)), widths=(5,11,5), names=["TypeA", "TypeB", "Charles"])` should work.

Comment: So some_list_of_strings would be like some_list_of_strings=['-first line-','-second-line-', ...] etc?

Comment: That's right.  Note though that if each line doesn't end with `\n`, you should use `'\n'.join(some_list_of_strings)` so that you're not feeding it one long line.

Comment: Thank You, Arigato, DSM.

Answer (score 1):

After you get the list, just use `strip` on all of its element:

```
data = [s.strip() for s in line]
```

Demo:

```
>>> line = ["ABCD ", "EFGHIJK LMN", "OP QR"]
>>> data = [s.strip() for s in line]
>>> data
['ABCD', 'EFGHIJK LMN', 'OP QR']
```